# Pages from adobe.com have messed up fonts

Tags: fonts

Pages on adobe.com have terrible looking fonts.  I seriously doubt the problem is on their end.  I have ClearType disabled on my Windows Server 2003.

Pages such as http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2010/09/choosing-type-for-screen.html look terrible at my end; here's a screenshot of a section of that page:

[image]

It looks the same whether I view from Internet Explorer 8 or Chrome.  I don't know of any other websites where the fonts are so rough-looking.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably *because* you have ClearType disabled. Some fonts are made with the assumption that it is enabled; they look really bad otherwise. Try enabling it and seeing if they look better.